# attached to launch centre

Tags: launcher, eclipse, lazarus

I unattached Eclipse from the Launch Centre and installed Lazarus, which does not attach to the launch centre. I would like to learn if there any commands to attach my application to the launch centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open dash and type Lazarus and drag it to launcher

Comment: Thanks a million for the information and help, Regards, Inung